IOS IPAD 13" flyoutpage not closing completely in .NET MAUI app. Any work around or ideas how to fix it?
I have implemented a Flyoutpage on my .NET MAUI app. It work on mobile phones Android or IOS. Apple requires it to also work on an IPAD 13"(or 12.9") . The problem is when opening the Flyoutpage it fills the screen on the IPAD in portrait mode. When you swipe to close it, it closes only 25% and 75% of the screen remains of the Flyoutpage . When in landscape mode it works similar as to desktop where it applies the split page and shows the menu. Any ideas what is wrong I am using the sample Flyoutpage that comes with the MAUIKIT.
My flyoutpage XAML Layout
<FlyoutPage
    x:Class="SignatureSeries.AppFlyout"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:SignatureSeries.Extensions"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SignatureSeries"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SignatureSeries.Views"
    FlyoutLayoutBehavior="{OnIdiom Phone='Popover',
                             Tablet='Popover',
                                   Desktop='Split'}" >
</FlyoutPage>

My FlyoutPage code Behind
public partial class AppFlyout : FlyoutPage
{
    public AppFlyout()
    {

        try
        {
            Flyout = new MainMenuPage(LaunchPageInDetail);
          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Information", ex.Message, "OK");
            });

            throw;
        }


    }
    private void LaunchPageInDetail(Page page)
    {
        Detail = page;

        if (!((IFlyoutPageController)this).ShouldShowSplitMode)
        {
            IsPresented = false;
         
        }
    }
}


You can check this issue FlyoutPage issues on iOS Tablets on the Github.

I checked the issues and none where actually similar to what I experienced. I did however manage to get it working as expected.
I first on the FlyoutPage initialize I set the
Flyout.Visible = false.

I then subscribe to the Property change
// Subscribe to PropertyChanged for IsPresented
 this.PropertyChanged += OnFlyoutPagePropertyChanged; 

Then on the
private void OnFlyoutPagePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(IsPresented))
    {
        // Check if Flyout is closed
        if (!IsPresented)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Flyout has been closed.");
            // Perform additional actions here
       
            Flyout.IsVisible = false;


        }
        else
        {
           
            Flyout.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
}

This seems to draw the flyout page and it display correctly on Iphone or IPad.
